# Can't access Bootstrap locally

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have been trying very hard to find the right path to my local Bootstrap 5 files, but what ever I do it's not finding it. At the moment I am in index.html (react). There I'm doing this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script  src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and yes Bootstrap files are inside the css and js folder. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

It seems it is working at localhost:3000 but not in localhost:5001 (this one is with server/backend). What is the reason?

Comment: @codemonkey yes !

Comment: Is it a built app or you're in dev?

Comment: @codemonkey hey it seems it is working at localhost:3000 but not in localhost:5001 (this one is with server), what is the reason ?

Comment: So, it's working at the URL set up to serve the frontend files, which is where those files are, but not from the URL set up to serve the backend files, which is not where those files are? I think that's pretty self-explanatory, yes?

Comment: @HereticMonkey then why using bootstrap cdn link everythings fine?